# Drupal 8.5.3 getting error The specified library &quot;bootstrap/drupal.ajax&quot; does not exist

Tags: drupal-8

We have a site running Drupal 8.5.3 in a production environment. I believe it's hosted inside a Docker container inside Azure. Folders such as sites, modules etc are mapped so we can update files within those folders.

Recently I installed a fresh copy of Drupal onto a development server, moved the production database across to this environment and also moved across the folders, sites, modules, profiles and libraries. This gave us a development environment to work on to make some changes.

In the development environment we've added some new content types, paragraphs and a couple of new pages. We've tried to move these changes over to the production environment by dumping the database and importing it into a database in the live environment, changing the settings.php file in production to point to the new database, and we've deleted the modules, profiles, themes folders from production and replaced them with the folders from the development environment.

The issue is that when we do this, we get an error from Drupal when trying to view the site;

```
The specified library &quot;bootstrap/drupal.ajax&quot; does not exist.
```

If we switch back to using the old production database, the site works fine.

I've spent hours uploading files, deleting files, clearing Drupal cache, copying across the database again and I cannot get the database from development to work in production.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks